# Mirroring triangles using recursion Java

Tags: java, recursion

I need help making a mirrored triangle in java like in the question: [Creating a double mirrored triangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35830511/creating-a-double-mirrored-triangle).
However it needs to be done using recursion. I figured out how to make two versions of the triangle already:
*
**
and 
** 
 * 
But I cant figure out the other alignments. That part of the assignment is not graded, it is to help our understanding so we can figure out how to do the mirrored image.

```
public static String triangle(int size) {
    if (size == 0)
        return "";

    String dots = triangle(size - 1);
    dots = dots + ".";
    System.out.println(dots);

    return dots;
}

//right alignment- small to big
public static String triangle2(int size) {
    if (size == 0)
        return "";

    String dots = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        dots = dots + ".";
    }


    System.out.println(dots);
    return dots + triangle2(size - 1);

}
public static String triangle3(int size) {
    if (size == 0)
        return "";    

    String spaces = "";
    for (int i=0; i < size-1; i++){
        spaces = spaces + " ";
    }


    String dots = "";
    dots = dots + ".";

    System.out.println(spaces + dots);
    return spaces + dots + triangle3(size-1);

}
```

Comment: So when you are doing recursion, you need to come up with a base case and a recursive case. Can you try to do that on your own first, and then post what you think these cases should be?

Comment: i have been working on this for 3 hours and i am so frustrated. Before I move on to the mirroring part, I really want to get triangle 3 to work because it is one side of the mirror, but I cant seem to figure out how to print both the spaces and the dots the right way at the same time.

Comment: The answers to the linked question shows many solutions. Take one of them and convert a `for` loop into a recursion, and you'll be done.

Comment: yeah i know ideally that is what I should be able to do, but besides simple math problems like exponents and factorials, I cant seem to understand how to convert from iterative to recursive

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution, using two different recursive methods:

```
public static void printMirrorTriangle(int size) {
    printRow(1, size);
}
private static void printRow(int row, int size) {
    System.out.println(repeat('*', row) + repeat(' ', (size - row) * 2) + repeat('*', row));
    if (row < size)
        printRow(row + 1, size);
}
private static String repeat(char c, int count) {
    return (count == 0 ? "" : c + repeat(c, count - 1));
}
```

*Test*

```
printMirrorTriangle(4);
```

*Output*

```
*      *
**    **
***  ***
********
```

Comment: i appreciate the solution, but it is a little too advanced for me. I am a little confused  as to how it is functioning