# Java Triangle Recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I am having trouble printing out triangles recursively involving spaces and asterisks. Apparently stringbuffer or stringbuilder may be necessary to calculate the correct number of spaces and asterisks, but I am having a bit of difficulty. The 2 triangles should look like:

```
****  
 ***
  **
   *
```

and

```
   *
  **
 ***
****
```

---

```
public static String printTriangle(int num)
{
    if (num == 0) {
        return "";
    } 

    String dots = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        dots = dots + "*";
    }

    System.out.println(dots);
    return printTriangle(num-1) + dots;
}

  public static String printTriangle2(int num) {
    if (num == 0) {
        return "";
    }

    String dots = printTriangle2(num-1);
    dots = dots + ".";

    String spaces = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        spaces = spaces + " ";
    }

    String line = spaces + dots;
    System.out.println(line);
    return line;
}
```

This is what I have so far. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the output currently:

```
****
***
**
*
 .
   ..
      ...
          ....
```

Comment: And what does your attempt output? Did you debug through it? What did that show?

Comment: is this question different from your other question? it looks the same and there are answers there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52683273/mirroring-triangles-using-recursion-java

Comment: yes because I want it done in a simpler way. the other output is more complicated and a little hard to follow

Comment: you could pass in another parameter `spaces` to keep track of the number of spaces you would need to print (i.e. `printTriangle (int num, int spaces )`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the follwing code and  call with    `step=0`

```
printTriangle(4,0)
printTriangle2(4,0)

public static String printTriangle(int num, int step)
{
    if (num == 0) {
        return "";
    } 

    String ast = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        ast = ast + "*";
    }
    String sps = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < step; i++) {
        sps = sps + " ";
    }


    System.out.println(sps+ast);
    return printTriangle(num-1, step+1) ;
}
```

```
    public static String printTriangle2(int num, int step)
{
    if (num == 0) {
        return "";
    } 

    String ast = "";
    for (int i = 0; i <= step; i++) {
        ast = ast + "*";
    }
    String sps = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        sps = sps + " ";
    }


    System.out.println(sps+ast);
    return printTriangle2(num-1, step+1) ;
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for helping me solve this problem using my code and my logic. I actually understand it now!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fairly simple implementation:

```
static void printTriangle(int n, int len)
{
  if(n == len) return;

  printRow(n, len);
  printTriangle(n+1, len);
  printRow(n, len);
}

static void printRow(int n, int len)
{
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++) System.out.print(" ");
  for(int i=n; i<len; i++) System.out.print("*");
  System.out.println();
}
```

Test:

```
printTriangle(0, 4);
```

Output:

```
****
 ***
  **
   *
   *
  **
 ***
****
```

Although I like this:

```
static void printTriangle(String s)
{
  if(!s.contains("*")) return;

  System.out.println(s);
  printTriangle(" " + s.replaceFirst("\\*", ""));
  System.out.println(s);
}
```

Called with

```
printTriangle("****");
```